# Is WGL required for initializing OpenGL on Windows?

Tags: opengl

WGL seems to depend on GDI which is now deprecated. Is WGL required, and if not, how do I initialize OpenGL without it in a non-deprecated way?

Comment: To be fair, AMD implements the EGL API in their Windows driver independent from WGL, but using it will not get you an OpenGL context; rather, you will receive an OpenGL ES context. For all intents and purposes in modern Windows you need a WGL ICD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WGL is the only API to create OpenGL contexts in Windows.

> GDI which is now deprecated

Says who? The Microsoft marketing department. But the same guys also claim that OpenGL was obsolete.

GDI+ builds on top of GDI and WPF has a different target audience.

> how do I initialize OpenGL without it in a non-deprecated way?

Using WGL. You might find a EGL wrapper around it somewhere, but it will still fall back to WGL.

Comment: Says the company behind Windows. And I don't think they are claiming OpenGL is obsolete, but that their own implementation is, which is just at the 1.1 version. And GDI+ is 10 times slower? So I think Microsoft is definitely trying to move away from this very old api, and I'd prefer not to use it then. But very well, it's the only way. Thanks for the helpful answer. But basically OpenGL currently depends on deprecated functionality, I don't know enough about Windows to know if OpenGL can easily fix that in the future or not, but let's hope so.

Comment: @user1594138: There is no need to fix anything, to be honest. Yes, WGL is closely tied to GDI and GDI is deprecated, but once a (***hardware accelerated***) render context has been created, vendor-written OpenGL ICDs (Installable Client Driver) take over. These ICDs are very much modern, in fact the things like GPU memory management / scheduling go through the very same low-level DXGI (DirectX Graphics Infrastructure) interface as a modern D3D10/11 driver on Windows Vista+. The parts you see may sit atop some ancient and deprecated technology, but under the hood it is all shiny and new.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: but what about presentation? Just about every documentation regarding the DWM mentions they really don't like having GDI in the mix.

Comment: @mirh: They're mostly concerned about GDI drawing functions, and for what it's worth OpenGL doesn't like to be mixed with those either. The interaction with GDI only happens to get a handle to the underlying drawable structures, to then set (bypassing GDI) the pixelformat and later on to make the context current (also bypassing the GDI). When WGL was created, GDI was the only drawing API around, and that's what it was interfaced with. Modernizing these affairs is something that's simply not on Microsoft's roadmap; don't concern yourself too much with this.

Comment: @mirh: From a practical point of view, Microsoft is *famous* for maintaining compatibility with historic Windows versions as far back as possible. Furthermore there's just too much professional productivity software out there (CAD, 3D modelling) that relies on OpenGL and never will be ported to DirectX, so Microsoft can't cut those ties without some serious backlash.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Tagging you, I accidently mistagged @ mirh